# Google fonts not working from Android XML layout file (some of the time) needs to be set programatically via ResourcesCompat.getFont

Tags: android, textview, google-font-api, google-fonts, android-textattributes

Google recently made Google Fonts available for use in Android, which is great! The simplest/most straight forward way to apply a font to a TextView (assuming the font already exists in the *font* resource folder, which is made very easy by selecting your TextView in the design window) is to apply it directly to the XML of the TextView as such

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat" />
```

This worked great in the first Activity I tried it in, but then when I attempted to use the exact same setup in a second activity it failed. The fonts would not be read from the XML property `android:fontFamily`, even for the exact same fonts I had used in the previous activity.

Fortunately I was still able to get the fonts to work by setting them programmatically like this

```
@FontRes private static final int TITLE_FONT = R.font.acme;
@FontRes private static final int SUBTITLE_FONT = R.font.acme;
@FontRes private static final int TEXT_FONT = R.font.ubuntu;
@FontRes private static final int VIEW_LISTING_FONT = R.font.nunito;

    Typeface titleTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, TITLE_FONT);
    Typeface subtitleTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, SUBTITLE_FONT);
    Typeface textTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, TEXT_FONT);
    Typeface viewListingTypeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, VIEW_LISTING_FONT);
    _businessOwnerView.setTypeface(titleTypeface);
    _businessNameView.setTypeface(subtitleTypeface);
    _descriptionView.setTypeface(textTypeface);
    _viewListingButton.setTypeface(viewListingTypeface);
```

But this is a pain and becoming cumbersome. I think I am just going to subclass TextView and read the fonts myself so I can use them in XML again as I feel like this is a bug (given it worked in one activity and not another, and also because this is a relatively new feature) but would like to know if anyone else has run into this problem or has any ideas for a solution?